# ASP.NET Web Form is not displaying data in GridView

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, webforms

I'm having some trouble here.

I got a DataTable from my database and I want to use it to be the datasource of my GridView.

The problem: when I set the datasource of this GridView with my DataTable, nothing happens. But if I set the datasource of another component (like ListItem), the data is shown.

What do I do with it?
Follow the code below:

```
<!-- Here I have a ListView. When I set the datasource, the data is showed. -->
<asp:ListView ID="listviewCustomers" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="myLabel" text="<%# bind('Name') %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>


<!-- Here I have a GridView. When I set the datasource, nothing happens. -->
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridviewPassageiros">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="myLabel" text="<%# bind('Name') %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You mave have to paste your code behind or parts of it.

Comment: You are setting up Datasource but are you binding it?

Comment: Yes, the DataSource is setted and the "DataBind" method is called.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple case could be a missing call to "DataBind" of "gridviewPassageiros".
Another option is to add dummy-content.

Code-Behind

```
public void Page_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
  if (!IsPostback)
  {
    gridviewPassageiros.DataSource = GetPassageiros();
    gridviewPassageiros.DataBind();
  }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridviewPassageiros">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <h1>TEST</h1>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="myLabel" text="<%# bind('Name') %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

CODE FROM COMMENT:

```
DAOPassenger objDAOPassenger = new DAOPassenger(); 
gridviewPassageiros.DataSource = objDAOPassenger.GetAllPassangers(); 
gridviewPassageiros.DataBind();
```

have you checked, the result of `GetAllPassangers`?

Comment: Hey, mo. Thanks for your reply.
Neither this way - putting the <h1> tags into template - the data is displayed.
I've already called the DataBind method, and nothing happened.
Any other idea?

Thanks!

Comment: please show the portion of your code where you assign the "DataSource"-Property, this might help us to help you.

Comment: Here is the code where I set the "DataSource" property:
    
DAOPassenger objDAOPassenger = new DAOPassenger();
gridviewPassageiros.DataSource = objDAOPassenger.GetAllPassangers();
gridviewPassageiros.DataBind();

And here I have the code for display my GridView:

<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridviewPassangers" emptyDataText="None.">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="labelPassangerName" text="<%# bind('Name') %>" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

Any idea?

Comment: indent it by 4 chars or use the 'button' in the toolbar

Comment: in comments it works a bit different :) use ` to escapse code or (have a look at the help)[http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting]

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Also make sure you bind the data correctly

eg

```
 if (dt.Rows.Count>0) 
 {
    GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, huMpty duMpty!
Well, the data is correctly setted, but the gridview don't display! So strange, huh?

Answer (score 0):

I see two Problem in your Code:
try this

```
Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'
```

insted of

```
text="<%# bind('Name') %>"
```

also i can't see the DataSourceID in your Code

Hope I Helped

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ibrahem!
Neither this way the gridview is displayed. The message from "EmptyDataText" property also ins't displayed. So strange. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

DataSourceID is missing .. that is no data source is provided to your grid.

Comment: you just need a DataSoureID if you use a DataSourceProvider.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Amrita.
I use the same DataTable to set the DataSource of a ListView, and the data is displayed, but in my GridView nothing happens. That's my big problem! Hahaha